# non isomorphic algebraically closed fields

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am trying to find all algebraically closed fields(up to isomorphism). I found that the field of all algebraic numbers over $\mathbb Q$ is algebraically closed and I also know that the field of complex numbers $\mathbb C$ is also algebraically closed. I want to know that is there exist any other algebraically closed field or not. If exist then what are they.

Comment: Every field has an algebraic closure, so there are many such fields. Each finite field $\Bbb F_p$ has its own algebraic closure; function fields $\Bbb Q(t)$ have algebraic closures; etc.

Comment: To follow on with Greg Martin comment, you can have [fields of arbitrary infinite cardinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296889/fields-of-arbitrary-cardinality) and from them build algebraic closure of the same arbitrary infinite cardinal

Comment: On the other hand, algebraically closed fields of fixed characteristic all behave “roughly similarly” without being isomorphic – their first-order theory being complete, any first-order statement holding in one of them holds in any other.

Comment: Under the axiom of choice an algebraically closed field is determined (up to isomorphism) by its characteristic and the cardinality of a transcendental basis (over $\Bbb{Q}$ or $\Bbb{F}_p$). Conversely for each cardinal $c$ there is the algebraic closure of the field of rational functions in $c$ variables.